# Valid example for C# TransactionSearch method PayPal API

Tags: c#, datetime, soap, paypal, nvp

I've been trying to find a valid and good example on how to use the PayPal's TransactionSearch method which returns the history of all transactions for the specified time range..

I've stumbled upon this example:

```
AccountType accountType = AccountType.Live;
tblPayPalAccount account = PayPalAPICallHelperSOAP.GetAccount(accountType);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);


    using (PayPalAPIInterfaceClient client = new PayPalAPIInterfaceClient())
    {
        client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0");
        UserIdPasswordType userIdPasswordType = PayPalAPICallHelperSOAP.GetUserIdPasswordType(account);
        CustomSecurityHeaderType header = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        header.Credentials = userIdPasswordType;

        TransactionSearchReq request = new TransactionSearchReq();

        request.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();

        request.TransactionSearchRequest.Version = account.version;
        request.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = startDate;

        request.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = endDate;

        TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponseType = client.TransactionSearch(ref header, request);
    }
```

But most of these classes are unavailable. I've installed PayPal .NET SDK and PayPal Merchant API...

Am I missing something here or these classes have been removed/ ie. new method of writing this request has been introduced?

Edit: just found a solution (For those who might need this in the future)

```
  DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2016, 11, 1);
                DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 1);

                TransactionSearchReq req = new TransactionSearchReq();
                req.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
                req.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = startDate.ToString();
                req.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = endDate.ToString();

                PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration.GetConfig());
//Configuration.GetConfig(); => load the NVP SOAP data from config file...

                TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponseType = service.TransactionSearch(req);
                return transactionSearchResponseType;
```